# Power Series Expansion for bouncing ball

Tags: calculus, power-series

I'm trying to solve the following question by employing the expansion of $\frac1{1-x} = 1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots$ but have hit a hurdle.

> Associated with each rubber ball is a bounce coefficient $b$. When the ball is dropped from a height $h$, it bounces back to a height of $bh$.

> Suppose that the ball is dropped from an initial height $h$, and then is allowed to bounce forever. Use the expansion of $\frac1{1 - x}$ in powers of $x$ to help come up with a clean formula that measures, in terms of $b$ and $h$, the total up-down distance the ball travels in all of its bouncing.

Any advice on how to tackle this?

Comment: Suppose you could use your knowledge of a sum of a geometric series.  How would you tackle this problem?

Comment: Can you compute the height of the bounce on the $n$th bounce?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The required distance is
$$h+bh+bh+b^2h+b^2h+b^3h+b^3h+\cdots=h+2h\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b^n$$